# R simple equivalent to strcat

Tags: r

I would like a way to concatenate an array of strings into a single string.

Is there a more basic way to concatenate values in an array than my 'paste.c' function below?

```
paste(1,2,3)    # result: "1 2 3"
paste(c(1,2,3)) # result: "1" "2" "3", analogous to Unix 'paste' result
paste.c <- function(y) {
    as.character(
        tapply( X        = y, 
                INDEX    = rep.int(1, length(y)), 
                FUN      = paste, 
                sep      = "", 
                collapse = ""
        )
    )
}
paste.c(c(1,2,3)) # result: "123", which is what I need at the moment
```

Comment: Perhaps read `?paste`'s description of the `collapse` argument...?

Comment: If you use it often `paste.c <- function(...) paste(..., collapse='')`

Comment: `paste(1,2,3, sep="")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
  paste(c(1,2,3), collapse = '')
```